# Autolayout and ios5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using storyboards. I have used auto layout but its not working with ios5 and give crashes so I want to remove it. However, How can I uncheck the auto layout. But if I uncheck auto layout, How can i set my screens for both iPhone 4 and 5

Regards

Comment: What are the error messages when it crashes?

Comment: You can use plain old autoresizing masks (aka strings & struts).

Comment: @MikeD NSLayoutConstaint because of version 5 of IOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable autolayout in IB but set the constraints programatically in the view controller, based on whether the iOS version on the device supports it or not by, for example, checking if the NSLayoutConstraint class can be found:

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"NSLayoutConstraint")) {
    //create constraints
}
```

More info on creating the actual constraints can be found here: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_iOS_6_Auto_Layout_Constraints_in_Code

Answer (score 1):

You can uncheck auto layout from the Storyboard Utilities tab. If you aren't using auto layout you can use strings and structs or make adjustments programatically.

[image]

Comment: actually my question is, how to make adjustments with strings and structs :) I am trying to use autoresizing atm :) and its working fine so far

Answer (score 0):

For the use the Auto Layout use the springs in the story board for each view depending on how you want to resize them! Naturally you will need

```
    view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth
```

In the StoryBoard when you set a string or strut that means you are fixing that distance eg: if you select the bottom spring the distance of the view from the bottom is fixed which is same as the above UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin.